# Get the full list of my own YouTube channel's subscriber

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get the full list of my own channel's subscribers, but this does not work.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key=[API_KEY]
```

I am following the official documentation https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list

But get this error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized.",
        "domain": "youtube.parameter",
        "reason": "authorizationRequired",
        "location": "mine",
        "locationType": "parameter"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are only using an api key which will only give you access to public data, using mine is private user data and will require authorization.

This can be seen in the documentation page for
[Subscriptions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) States

[image]

This means that you must be authorized using Oauth2 to access the subscriptions for this channel.  You will then have an access token that you can send as an authorization header bearer token.

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mine=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Thank you. I missed that detail completely. Seems like what I'm exactly looking for. Are you aware if this function comes with any specific limits? Can I really get the list of all of my subscribers even if there are 10k of them? I read somewhere that hidden subscribers (privacy setting enabled) won't show here AND the list is always limited to 1k?

Comment: are you getting the next page of results?

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it results in an error every time. Is the ACCESS_TOKEN my client ID or client secret? ```curl \
  'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?mine=true&key=[I_PUT_MY_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [I_PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_OAuth_2.0_Here]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed```

Comment: I_PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_FROM_OAuth_2.0_Here   <--- you need to put access token their not the client secrete.   An access token is a bearer token. the client id and client secrete are just used to help you request access of the user and get an access token.   [Understanding Oauth2 with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)